# What is the best way to add your custom JS files and fonts to your own distribution of UIkit

Tags: javascript, css, code-structure, getuikit

We can create our own distribution of UIKit using the gulp task:

```
gulp dist -t THEME-NAME
```

This will create a folder `dist` and generate your minified CSS and JS files from the LESS files.

For my project I have custom JS files and FONTS. If I put subfolders for fonts and js in my THEME folder, they are not taken into consideration by the gulp task.

If I put them in the `src`folder they are then added to my distribution.

Is this good practice or what should I do to keep code out of the uikit code and then generate my own distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to structure my folders as follow.

I decided to use uikit as a vendor library. I use Laravel's Elixir to compile the less files and minify the javascript and CSS files.

Thus I put the uikit in the vendor folder in the assets folder along with my custom fonts. I have the following structure:

```
Assets
 |__CSS
 |__images
 |__javascript
 |__less
 |__vendor
    |__uikit
    |  |__js
    |  |__less
    |
    |__fonts
       |__css
       |__fontName
```

Then I run elixir's gulp and publish my assets under `/public` and `.copy`the images and other needed folders under that public rep.